# WebApi 2 and EF 6.1 fails serialization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-6.1

Im having a problem with WebApi2 and EF 6.1 (code first)

I have 2 models (master-detail)

```
namespace testApp.Model
{
    public class Master
    {
        public Master () {
            Details = new HashSet<Detail>();
        }

        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_ComplexIndex", 0, IsUnique=true)]
        public long UserID { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_ComplexIndex", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        public Nullable<long> TenantID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MasterID")]
        public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_Master")]
        public long MasterID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MasterID")]
        public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ApiController

```
    public class MasterController : ApiController
    {
        private TestContext db = new TestContext();

        // GET api/Master
        public IQueryable<Master> GetMasters()
        {
            return db.Masters;
        }  //THIS FAILS

        //GET api/Master/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Master))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMaster(long id)
        {
            Master master = db.Masters.Find(id);
            if (master == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(master);
        } //THIS WORKS FINE!
    }
```

if I execute a get with `api/Master/1`

```
{"Detailss":[{"ID":1,"MasterID":1,"Desc":"test"}],"ID":1,"UserID":1,"TenantID":1}
```

but if I execute `api/Master` the error message I got is:

```
    {"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; 
charset=utf-8'.",
"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,
"InnerException":{
  "Message":"An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'Details' on 
 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Master_6110B4795BCBF52E3140C9F99EB1E28BF43BA97EB02A532B9C89FD1996CE11E9'.",
"ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
"StackTrace":"   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues
(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter ...
```

I'm forcing the response in JSON in WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

// Remove default XML handler
var matches = config.Formatters
                    .Where(f => f.SupportedMediaTypes
                                    .Where(m => m.MediaType.ToString() == "application/xml" ||
                                                m.MediaType.ToString() == "text/xml")
                                    .Count() > 0)
                    .ToList();
foreach (var match in matches)
    config.Formatters.Remove(match);
```

**Important**: If I use EF 6.0 (removing index attribs and others attribs not supporteds) this works fine. So I'm confused!

Thanks in advance.

Ps: I'm really new with C# (and WebApi and EF)

**EDIT**: As [Wiktor Zychla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941240/wiktor-zychla) suggest, just change `IQueryable` by `IList` and `return db.Masters.ToList()` and now works fine! But why IQueryable fails if the scaffold generates it this way? and why IQueryable works with EF 6.0 and not 6.1? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need the `ForeignKey` attribute on both sides of the relation?

Comment: No, I tried with and without it and I have the same error. (I check and the structure generated is the same)

Comment: And if you `return db.Masters.ToList()` to force the materialization?

Comment: I changed the signature and this works! but, have any Idea why fails with IQueryable?? the scaffold generates this way

Comment: Seems that serializing lazy loaded entities is done after the context is disposed or something like this. Anyway, I wonder why it works with the older version as this is a common issue and a common workaround.